# Creating Private Pages for People on WordPress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration, user-roles

I have a WordPress website that I use to introduce our Wedding company. I want to add the functionality that I can create/generate login credentials for each of my client. And when I give them the credentials and a url, they can login on that url using those credentials which can redirect them to a specific page that displays only their photos/videos.

Can you suggest how I can add this function to my site? Do I create a new page for each user every time and password protect it or are there some authentic plugins that can help me achieve this in free?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create New Page or open existing page from WordPress admin panel

In Visibility option , select Private
One more option in visibility allows to setup password for pages
[View This Image for Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIwyV.png)

Comment: Actually I might have one central page i want user to be redirected to after login, from there, user can be able to visit the images page or videos. So wouldn't it be too much work creating these pages each time and making them password protected